# Is there any way to change the color of bars in bar chart in Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for drawing bar charts in android application. Its a single series Bar graph.I want to show all the bars in different colors. Please guide me with any help available.

Answer (score 1):

Single series cannot provide multiple color bars,because each series can provide only one color for the bar its generating.In order to get each bar in each color we need to use multiple series